# ASP.NET Membership Roles list in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, roles, membership

I want to create and show list of ASP.NET Membership Roles in my MVC application. The user will select the role and it will be saved in database using entity framework. Any help to implement this?

Comment: do you want the full solution or what is stopping you? UI implementation or database access or business logic?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague and looks like you ask everything, like a ready to use solution.

For the layering of a MVC and MS Entity Framework solution I suggest you read my answer here: [MVC3 and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474267/mvc3-and-entity-framework/7474357#7474357)

for introduction and QuickStart on ASP.NET MVC I suggest you to go here: http://www.asp.net/mvc and follow one of those intro videos, there are some videos showing already plenty of crucial details in just about half an hour. Then once you are ok with this all you can ask more specific questions here in SO but not just "*I want this and that all together please make it for me and share the solution.*" ;-)