# Commonly forgotten tasks during a website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

I'm building a pretty stock standard N-tier ASP.NET MVC website, and I'm trying to think of all the little miscellaneous tasks that people often forget to do when building a site.

Off the top of my head things like:

- Custom error pages
- Maintenance downtime handling
- Load testing
- etc.

What are the common things that people often forget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People tend for forget to test the deployment and upgrade process.

Deploying the system to a production-like environment early on during the development process will uncover (often forgotten) external dependencies and configuration settings that need to be tweaked before production. Plus it will force the team to start thinking about the upgrade process and how to automate it.

Comment: yeah, environments and operational tasks are often forgotten about

Answer (score 1):

Some examples of such tasks (from my own experience):

- make website running well with javascript disabled
- forms validation (especially limiting size of the input)
- protection against CSRF and other kinds of attacks (penetration tests)
- logging server errors (using elmah or sth similar)
- make web site logo displaying on the address bar
- SEO optimization (meta tags, page keywords, descriptions, sitemap etc)

Edit: added point about javascript.

Comment: thanks Lucasus, although the JavaScript one is really up to the customer, but a good point to think about in general

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the main mistake or misunderstanding of people starting using MVC is that they confuse the C of MVC, the Controller, with the Business Logic and the M, Model with the Data Acess Layer or entity model.

I have given this answer a while ago and there are some comments about this confusion of the fact that MVC is only about UI controlling and modeling, it's surely not replacing other NON UI related layers... [MVC3 and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474267/mvc3-and-entity-framework/7474357#7474357)

Comment: Thanks Davide, but i was thinking more along the lines of common tasks that are always left to last, or never done on sites, not necessarily specific to MVC, although I did mention MVC specifically, so my fault