# Preferred presentation pattern for ASP.NET with option to build other UI technologies later?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, c#-4.0, n-tier-architecture

I came with this mind problem lately when I discussed about a project involves various technologies such as WCF, EF 4 etc. So the idea is to keep a basic architerctural model, practises and layering, separation concerns and other stuff that should mind when you want to build something maintainable and testable.

So I came with this, what should I choose to implement when it comes to the presentation pattern? Maybe later I will need to use some of the layers to create a Windows Phone app to show some data from the service layer, or create a Silverlight client, a winforms client etc...

MVVM is presented better for Windows Phone, Silverlight the best option.
MVP as the winforms suitable presentation pattern.
MVC is best for ASP.NET Webforms? (seen some net examples using MVP for webforms).

[EDIT] Seems like a solution could be implement different approach for every UI and use tha same business logic and validation layer!

I guess you could use whatever you want...but is there anyone out there faced such a dillema? and what was he done about to solve it?

Thank you?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: [MVC3 and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474267/mvc3-and-entity-framework/7474357#7474357)

in fact depending on which UI technology or platform you would use details at the top are different but the rest of the layering will most likely stay the same...

Just a way to start with and get inspiration, ask more if you need other details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and your answer is what I often use on small projects too. My question though is more about the pattern when come into the presentation and BL layers....I guess though as you said depends on the UI tech or platform...so the best is to create different presentation pattern and implement the same BL to different platforms..

Comment: If BL is isolated by a service layer and runs on server side you dont need to rewrite it for every UI.