# EF database first edmx extension

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, partial-classes

I am using a database first approach with sqlce 3.5 and entity framework. Next I am extending my generated (.edmx file) partial class with external partial class properties where I implementing business logic. These extra properties are not required to be stored in database. Is this correct solution to the problem or are there any other more adequate solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

there is no black and white in general; in this case if you are using the partial classes properly so you add all your custom logic not to the auto-generated files from EF (edmx.cs...) but to other files in the same project, you can basically extend the `Entities` or the `ObjectContext` as you wish and you are free to regenerate any time when either database changes or you update the model in the designer.

I use this logic in general and more specifically I try to use the layering as I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7474357/559144 and I make all layers except the DAL fully independent from the EF. hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, actually I am doing minor changes to auto-generated files from EF (edmx.cs...) e.g. adding an event listener to a property, which ofcourse will be lost during code regeneration. Adding an extra layer to small application like mine it feels like overkill however I will consider it for the next project