# Silverlight 4.0 best way to write and read in database

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

Can anyone advice my which is best way to write and read data in database?
Silverlight enabled wcf service,
WCF Data Services
or something other?

Comment: Don't you think that if a **best way** existed *other ways* would have quickly faded away? The fact that there are different ways to achieve the same thing means that every solution has its pros and cons. So depending on your scenario and requirements (which by the way are absent from your question) one solution might be more adapted than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with **silverlight**, **WCF services** is the standard approach to access the **database**. Have a look at [this](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/using-wcf-ria-services).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends upon what you are trying to do,  but have a look at WCF RIA Services for Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Acid, you cannot reference anything else than a SilverLight control library or WCF from a SL application. My suggestion is to use a layered approach and define your BusinessLogic, Data Access Layer and Entities in a proper way then expose only what is absolutely needed to be used or called by the SL application via a Service Layer, see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474357/559144

this was originally about Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC but in fact is valid also for SL, if you do not plan to use Entity Framework only the DAL will be different and every other layer will stay the same, being isolated from the specific database engine and ORM you will use, if any.