# Can we do the DBContext in MVC3 with Razor?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can I connect to the DB using `DBContext` in MVC3 by defining the `ConnectionString` in Web.config?

If possible can anyone provide me some links too?

Comment: Yes, it is entirely possible, but there are certain things you have to do first. What you do depends on the approach you are taking e.g. code first, model first etc.

Comment: you can of course, but should you? no business logic or DAL project? do you really want to handle the EF connectivity in the UI level? see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7474357/559144

Comment: Yes, of course you can. See theese links: - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/01/29/asp-net-mvc-example-application-over-northwind-with-the-entity-framework.aspx - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8Ij3TeZKZo - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-

Comment: This will be more helpful for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff191186.aspx

Comment: @Jai Ganesh, do you want to use EF for this ?